# Do I need to create a new component in the React loop?

Tags: reactjs

For example, we want to display a phone book

```
John - 123
Alex - 487
...
Peter - 034
```

The question is how best to do it: all in one ContactList component

```
function ContactList (props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.contacts.map (item => <div> {item.name} - {item.phone} </ div>)}
      </ div>
   )
}
```

Or create additional ContactListItem component:

```
function ContactList (props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.contacts.map (item => <ContactListItem key = {item.id} name = {item.name} phone = {item.phone} />)}
      </ div>
   )
}

function ContactListItem (props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.name} - {props.phone} </ div>
      </ div>
   )
}
```

and why?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is: No, you don't need to or have to create a new component for your contact item. This is totally up to you.

But, what if this single JSX line will get bigger and more complex in the future?
What if you want to use some complex styles specially for this list item? 
Still, do you want to use like this or do you consider creating a new component?

If you don't create a new component then your main component will get fatter, more complex and hard to read. Also, it will be more difficult to maintain to this list item's logic after a while. But with a separate component all you need is go to the created component and do the changes there.

There isn't any rule for that. Refactoring, creating new components, separating your components (view, control, container, etc) is totally up to you. People generally say that, start writing your component. When you realize that it is getting bigger and more complex create new components and separate your logic.

Of course there are best practices. When you study other people's code you see those best practices and start to think according to that. But, as a learner I just start writing my component and refactor it when I need according to those best practices.

Further reading: [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

If you look the example they gave, even there is a separate component for category header. And here is what they say when there is need for a new component:

> One such technique is the single responsibility principle, that is, a
>   component should ideally only do one thing. If it ends up growing, it
>   should be decomposed into smaller subcomponents.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's sort of a 'phone book' type structure, a good approach (in my opinion) would be to map your array and prepare a **`table`** for rendering.
For your purposes, there's no need for a separate component. The final approach  really depends on how your data is structured, but let's say we have an array of objects like you suggested:

```
const contacts = [{
  name: 'John',
  phone: 23421
}, {
  name: 'Lisa',
  phone: 33665
}, {
  name: 'Rick',
  phone: 38885
}];


// Preparing the data for rendering
        const dataTable = contacts
            .map(item => {
                return (
                    <tr key={item.phone}> // Phone numbers are perfect keys, since they're unique as it gets :)
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.phone}</td>
                     </tr>
                  )});
```

*.... later in your code, in the* `render` *method to be precise, you would do something like this:*

```
                       <table>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>NAME</th>  // The 'Name' header
                                <th>PHONE</th> // The 'phone' header
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {dataTable}  // Here you would render your contacts data
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

See the snippet to give you an idea how that would ultimately look.
I truly hope this was helpful.

```js
const contacts = [{
  name: 'John',
  phone: 23421
}, {
  name: 'Lisa',
  phone: 33665
}, {
  name: 'Rick',
  phone: 38885
}];

// Preparing the data for rendering

console.log('NAME ' + '  ' + 'PHONE');

const dataTable = () => contacts.map(a => (a.name + '   ' + a.phone));


console.log(dataTable().join("\r\n"));
```